# How to validate whether the user has already logged in or not,to validate i use this line ([facebook isSessionValid]==NO) but always return NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, authentication

This is my code

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];

}
else {
    NSLog(@"session valid");

}

[self popUserShareFeed];
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Are you sure you are saving your data to standardUserDefaults so that it being returned? What makes you think isSessionValid should be anything other than NO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which library are you using.

Usually is an instance of FBSession and you can use:

session.isConnected